# How to get the calculation button work with the specific function already clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got a button to calculate the pound of fish but there multiple fish and when I switch on another fish I want the other calculation.

```
<table>            
    <tr>
        <th><button type="button" name="espece" id="masky"
             onclick="viewImageMasky('image')">Maskinonge</button>
        </th> 
        <th><button type="checkbox" name="espece" id="brochet"
             onclick="viewImageBrochet('image')">Brochet</button>
        </th> 
        <th><button type="checkbox" name="espece" id="achigan"
             onclick="viewImageAchigan('image')">Achigan petit 
             bouche</button>
        </th> 
        <th><button type="checkbox" name="espece" id="dore"
             onclick="viewImageDore('image')">Doré</button>
        </th> 
        <th><button type="checkbox" name="espece" id="esturgeon"
             onclick="viewImageEsturgeon('image')">Esturgeon</button> 
        </th>

        <tr>
            <div input type="img" id="image"></div>
        </tr>

        <button id="calculer" type="button" 
        onclick="viewPoidsDore(this)">calculer</button>
</table>
<script>

   function viewImageMasky(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML="<img src='Image/Masky.jpg'>";
    var longueur = document.getElementById("longueur").value;
    var circonference = document.getElementById("circonference").value;
    var resultat = Math.pow(circonference,2) * longueur / 800
    document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = "Poids: " + 
    resultat.toFixed(2) + " lbs";
} 

function viewImageBrochet(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML="<img 
    src='Image/Brochet.jpg'>";
    var longueur = document.getElementById("longueur").value;
    var circonference = document.getElementById("circonference").value;
    var resultat = longueur * Math.pow(circonference,2) / 1000;
    document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = "Poids " + 
    resultat.toFixed(2) + " lbs";
}
</script>
```

When I click on the button the first time it does not work because it's not the right function `onclick` from the button.

Comment: Where are the values of longueur and circonference for each fish stored? Also, your html code ain't complete since it's missing the elements also named longueur and circonference.

Comment: What is the `viewPoidsDore()` function supposed to do? Also, are the buttons actually supposed to be buttons, or checkboxes? (`"checkbox"` is not a valid `<button>` type, though it is a valid `<input>` type.